# How to programmatically ignore/skip tests with ScalaTest?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am running some tests with ScalaTest which rely on connections to test servers to be present. I currently created my own Spec similar to this:

```
abstract class ServerDependingSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  def serverIsAvailable: Boolean = {
    // Check if the server is available
  }
}
```

Is it possible to ignore (but not fail) tests when this method returns `false`?

Currently I do it in a "hackish" way:

```
"Something" should "do something" in {
  if(serverIsAvailable) {
    // my test code
  }
}
```

but I want something like

```
whenServerAvailable "Something" should "do something" in { 
  // test code
}
```

or

```
"Something" should "do something" whenServerAvailable { 
  // test code
}
```

I think I should define my custom tag, but I can only refer to the source code of `in` or `ignore` and I do not understand how I should plug in my custom implementations.

How should I accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use **Tags** to achieve this:

Documentation on how to use Tags : http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/tagging_your_tests

Adding and removing tagged test with command line parameters: http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner#specifyingTagsToIncludeAndExclude

**Example Code**:

```
import org.scalatest.Tag

object ServerIsAvailable extends Tag("biz.neumann.ServerIsAvailable")

"Something" should "do something" taggedAs(ServerIsAvailable) in { 
  // your test here
}
```

**Running the tests**

Running the tests is a bitt tricky. It only works for **testOnly** and **testQuick** not *test*.
In the example *testOnly* is short for *testOnly **

```
 sbt "testOnly -- -l biz.neumann.ServerAvailable"
```

Comment: I found this too, but the documentation only refers how to do it on the command line. However, I am running `sbt test` on Jenkins, and I want to programmatically skip the test when the server is not available.

Comment: so should the program react when the server is available or do you want to configure Jenkins to infer if the server is available and then have jenkins adapt to run the tests accordingly ?

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Currently I start and shutdown the test server programmatically (it is done with Docker on a test server by SSH'ing in there), but using Jenkins for this is the cleaner solution.

Comment: Regarding the edit: I use `testQuick` anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

You can use `assume` to [conditionally cancel a test](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_assertions):

```
"Something" should "do something" in {
  assume(serverIsAvailable)

  // my test code
}
```

or you can test for some condition yourself, and then use `cancel`:

```
"Something" should "do something" in {
  if(!serverIsAvailable) {
    cancel
  }

  // my test code
}
```

Comment: Assume is provided for this as well:
    
    `assume(server.isAvailable)`

Comment: Nice, I've adjusted the solution to show a full example.

Comment: should be without the !. I tried editing it but alas edits have to be at least 6 characters.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. fixed.

Comment: The outcome of a failed `assume` is a `org.scalatest.exceptions.TestCanceledException` and the whole suite ending up being aborted, and in consequence the whole build fails.
Not sure how is that different than `fail` (other than slightly different text output)

Comment: assume won't ignore/skip the tests, it will fail the whole unit test on CI/CD.

Comment: `cancel` too will terminate with an error message. `if(serverIsAvailable)` will skip the tests without error. Which is want as well. In my case I have a demo mode and when I compile for demo certain tests won't be needed.

Answer (score 10):

Here is some trick to skip a test based on a condition:

```
object WhenServerAvailable extends Tag(if (serverIsAvailable) "" else classOf[Ignore].getName)

"Something" should "do something" taggedAs WhenServerAvailable in { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to extract the condition into re-usable function:

```
import org.scalatest.{Assertion, Succeeded}
...

private def skipIfNoServer(testFun: => Assertion): Assertion = {
  if (serverIsAvailable) testFun
  else Succeeded
}
```

now you can write:

```
"Something" should "do something" in skipIfNoServer { 
  // test code
}
```