# How to skip Scala FunSuite tests under certain conditions?

Tags: scala, unit-testing

Suppose I have some tests that I want to only run if some environment variable is set and the value is valid. How do I do this with Scala FunSuite?

For instance:

```
class Tests extends FunSuite {
  before {
    // Test if the environment variable is set and value is valid
  }

  test("foo") {
    ...
  }
}
```

Test foo should only run when the check in the `before` call succeeded.
I tried to use `assume` but it failed with `TestCanceledException`.

Comment: Using `assume` is a possible mechanism. You only need to state your assumption in the main test body.

Comment: An involved but possibly appropriate solution could be using ScalaTest tags, see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32460592/5519149). You would check for the presence of the environment variable in a runner script or on Jenkins.