# When running SBT tests, what is the meaning of the different stats?

Tags: junit, sbt, scalatest

When running Scalatest and JUnit tests in SBT I receive a short summary at the end:

```
Passed: Total 1359, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 1358, Skipped 1, Ignored 13, Pending 1
```

I understand the meaning of the Total count, passed and ignored tests.
But what is the meaning of:

- Skipped?.  It looks like `Ignored` but there must be some difference.
- Pending?.  Aren't all the tests processed when the summary is given?
- Difference between `Failed` and `Errors`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an explanation:

- **Passed** means the test has run successfully.
- **Ignored** means the test has been tagged as ignored, probably because it needs to be fixed.
- **Skipped** means the `assume` condition is not satisfied, and the test is not run.  [More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460295/how-to-programmatically-ignore-skip-tests-with-scalatest)
- **Pending**, the test needs to be written.  [More information](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scalatest-mark-test-pending).
- Difference between **failed**/**error**: I'm not sure, but a failed test is a test that has a failed assertion (`TestFailedException` when using `ScalaTest`), whereas an error is an unexpected exception.
- **Total** count is the sum of:

  - Passed
  - Pending
  - Failed
  - Error