# Is there a way to run a test, but not mark the whole suite as failed if it fails?

Tags: scala, scalatest

Using Scalatest is there a way to mark a test as "optional". What I mean is running it anyway, but if it fails do not mark the whole test execution as failed (Return 0 instead of 1 to the shell).

I am aware that `ignore` exists as a replacement for `in`, but that does not exactly do what I am willing to do.

The reason I want to do this is that I have a project in which some tests might run in some networks and in some other fail.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if such option exists, but I think you better focus on solving the issue, or pass the test if the bad network is detected.

Comment: Another option is to use the `cancel` if bad network is detected, but it just aborts everything, is there a way to abort just a single test given a condition?

Comment: I think a simple `return` would do that.

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460295/how-to-programmatically-ignore-skip-tests-with-scalatest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [tags](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/tagging_your_tests) to define groups of tests. You could either whitelist or blacklist tests. If you want to whitelist tests, define a tag for each environment, and if a test should pass in that environment, give it that tag. Then, in each environment, include tests with the tag for that environment with `-n`. If you want to blacklist tests, tag tests that should fail in each environment, and then exclude tests with that tag using `-l`. Filtering tests is done with [runner configuration](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner).

Here is an example for blacklisting tests that require an external service.

```
object ServiceTest extends Tag("com.mycompany.tags.ServiceTest")

class MyTest extends WordSpec {
  "a foo" should {
    "connect to the service" taggedAs ServiceTest in {
      // ...
    }

    "do something without the service" in {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

You *could* also use `cancel()` to abort a test. I'm not sure what you mean by "aborts everything", only the current test case is canceled. But I think it is better to set expectations for tests to pass or fail in a given environment, and if they don't, investigate. Otherwise, it is too easy to ignore canceled tests if the network is unavailable and there is a real problem, say the url changed.

```
class MyTest extends WordSpec {
  "a foo" should {
    "connect to the service" in {
      if (serviceUnavailable()) cancel("Can't connect to service.")

      // ...
    }

    "do something without the network" in {
      // ...
    }
  }

  def serviceUnavailable(): Boolean = ???
}
```